# Parse error at line 0 and pos 0. XML document must have a top level element

Tags: php, xml

I have made this XML for a SMS sending API. I have been trying to make the correct XML from past 3 hours, but I'm getting this error :-
`Parse error at line 0 and pos 0. XML document must have a top level element.`

Have searched and read a lot of questions, but upto no luck. What might be wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <sms-teknik><operationtype>0</operationtype><flash>0</flash><multisms>0</multisms><maxmultisms>0</maxmultisms><compresstext>0</compresstext><udh/><udmessage>&lt;![CDATA['Testar sms app&#xD;
    V1.0']]&gt;</udmessage><smssender>dogbag</smssender><deliverystatustype>0</deliverystatustype><deliverystatusaddress/><usereplynumber>0</usereplynumber><usereplyforwardtype>0</usereplyforwardtype><usereplyforwardurl/><usereplycustomid/><usee164>0</usee164><items><recipient><orgaddress>+4612345678</orgaddress></recipient></items></sms-teknik>
```

Comment: Are you saving the file in the right format (perhaps ASCII)

Comment: The example XML can be loaded in DOMDocument::loadXml(). No error message.

Comment: I guess I am. I'm using the DOMDocument::saveXML function like this.
` $random_file = mt_rand(1000000,9999999999);
    echo $sxe->asXML(); 
    $sxe->saveXML("messages/message_$random_file.xml") or die();`

Comment: Read the manual of the SMS API and see what kind of `top level element` it requires, and then use it. (no link to API doc provided in question)